# Replication Setup what will be the value of MySQL auto_increment and offset in my.ini

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have setup master master mysql replication to sync changes in both server. But now I want to setup 6 server it is possible? I'm making 6 because when an area lost it connection over WAN it will continue it's service and then sync it when the connection is back. Now i'm having problem with the auto increment increment and auto increment offset to avoid data collision. And now i'm confuse with this I've read an article and made it worst. So now I wonder what should be the proper value of my auto increment and offset in each server. Thanks in advance.